# Generator ATS Without Relay

Tags: generator, ats

I going to make Generator ATS using arduino and don't want to use relays...Can I use mosfet in place of relays?

---

ATS stands for Automatic Transfer Switch.

My generator is 3KVA, and I want to drive solenoid and ignition using mosfet instead of relays.
I will use relay on main when generator supply transfers.

Comment: If you design it correctly I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: Is this for a bicycle dynamo or for an industrial sized diesel generator or something in between? Your question is hopelessly short of detail or context. Please edit your question.

Comment: Also, please explain acronyms such as ATS for those not familiar with the term.

Comment: I know what an Arduino is, unfortunately that's irrelevant, a PIC or a PI would work just as well. I don't know what an ATS is, or how big a generator you want to use, these are the vitally important details.

Comment: You need to explain more in detail what you are trying to do.  Power levels, and AC or DC generator would be good information to include in the question, as well as voltage.  Explaining acronyms (like ATS) would also help to make this question better.

Answer (score 1):

> I going to make Generator ATS using arduino and don't want to use relays...Can I use mosfet in place of relays?

Yes you could use MOSFET to control a solenoid (I don't know what for - starter switch?) and ignition.

- You need to design these to handle the currents and transients expected in normal and abnormal operation.
- You need to design the system to be fully isolated from the mains.
- You need to ensure that there is no danger of mains and generator ever being connected simultaneously to each other or via the load wiring.
- **You need to design the system to fail safe**. This means that the system should fail to a more restrictive and safer condition in the event of component failures. This includes running a risk analysis of potential failure modes of your micro-controller, PSU, MOSFET, etc. and analyse what happens if a transistor fails open-circuit or short-circuit. You can't predict which. e.g., What are the implications if the starter solenoid remains on indefinitely.

When you finish your analysis you will probably understand why relays are the preferred choice for this type of application.

Comment: well said transistor you are right I have to analysis.
I'm using 12v solenoid for injecting petrol into generator carborator...generator starts by petrol then converts to gas...and using mosfet as a relay...I think so ignition should work by mosfet because ignition solenoid takes 2 to 3amps.

Comment: There are the links you can see mosfet connections.

In 1st pic I used mosfet in place of relay to drive solenoid for injecting petrol.

In 2nd pic I'm checking AC power if ac available mosfet will be turn off otherwise mosfet turn on with 12v dc. I will use that 12volt to drive solenoid and iginition. is it ok?
 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19334358/mosfet.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19334358/mosfet2.png

Comment: Sorry That is starter and starter solenoid not ignition.